# Ajax function calling

Tags: ajax

I wrote the Ajax function like below.

It is not working properly. If I remove the `xmlhttp.status==400` then it is working. What mistake have I made in this example?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title> New Document </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getAjax()
            {
               if (window.XMLHTTPRequest)
               {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHTTPRequest();
               }
               else
               {
                   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlHTTP");
               }
               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
               {
                   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==400)
                   {
                       document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                   }
               }
               xmlhttp.open("GET","testajax.txt",true);
               xmlhttp.send(null);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Get content" onclick="getAjax()"><br>
        <div id="mydiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Another simple use is finding if a url exists, 
>   in HTTP there are various status codes returned by both HEAD and GET requests, 
>   200 means success, 404 means failure, and the others mean other things. 
>   See [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for a full explanation."

using the status property of the xmlhttp object provides you this status

```
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
           if (xmlhttp.status==200) alert("URL Exists!")
            else if (xmlhttp.status==404) alert("URL doesn't exist!")

          }
```

http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.2004.9.html

Answer (score 0):

The proper "`if`" condition should have been:-

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
{
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;            
}
```

For more deeper understanding, you can see this nice & detailed article from IBM Technical Library's [Mastering AJAX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro3/). Also, you could have easily used the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) API of the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library.

Hope it helps.

Comment: with xmlhttp.status==200 also not giving the out put.. sir

Comment: @Mihir - If possible, try with the jQuery AJAX API. It's the best one with little details requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Change `400` to `200`. That's an [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). [`200`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.1) means `OK`. [`400`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) means `Bad Request`.